# php utf-8 does not work

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying, put in header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); but not work

```
<?PHP
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  function randStr($rts=20){ 
  $act_chars = "ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ"; 
  $act_val = ""; 
  for($act=0; $act <$rts ; $act++) 
  { 
     mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
     $act_val .= $act_chars[mt_rand(0,strlen($act_chars)-1)]; 
  } 

  return $act_val; 
  } 
  $dene = randStr(16);
  print "$dene";
  ?>
```

output

```
K��A�CÞZU����EJ
```

Comment: which encoding does your php-file have?

Comment: notapad++   utf-8 without BOM

Comment: There are several mistakes. Don't use `[]` or `strlen()` on a multibyte string. Use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb_substr) and [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen).

Comment: _Note: As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is now done automatically._ http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php I would also store the string length to avoid the duplicated computing inside the loop: `$actCharLength = mb_strlen( $act_chars ) - 1;`

Comment: Check your texteditor's settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes. Don't use `[]` or `strlen()` on a multibyte string. Use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb_substr) and [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen).

Also set the internal encoding of the multibyte extension to `UTF-8`:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

You could also set the encoding on a per-function basis. See the specific function signatures for further details.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

function randStr($rts = 20) { 
  $act_chars = 'ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ';
  $act_val = '';
  $act_chars_last = mb_strlen($act_chars);

  for($act = 0; $act < $rts; $act++) { 
    $act_val .= mb_substr($act_chars, mt_rand(0, $act_chars_last), 1);
  } 

  return $act_val; 
} 
$dene = randStr(16);
print $dene;
```

---

- Replaced double quotes by single quotes (saves a tiny amount of time)
- Removed `mt_srand()` calls because they are automatically done as of PHP 4.2.0 (thanks to feeela for mentioning that in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682043/php-utf-8-does-not-work/19682244?noredirect=1#comment29233077_19682043))
- Saved the string length - 1 in a variable, so PHP doesn't need to recomputed it in every loop step.

If you want more insights on that topic, checkout the link from [deceze in the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682258/603003): [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: using the `mb_*` functions alone did not solve the problem; +1 for mentioning `mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );`

Comment: @feeela The file needs to be saved as UTF-8 "without" BOM in order to work. I tested it and it worked 100%.

Comment: It was in my test-setup, but I needed to add `mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );` to get the `mb_*` functions working correctly.

Comment: @feeela Me, too. The default encoding on my system is `ISO-8859-1` (call `mb_internal_encoding()` with no parameters to retrieve it).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assembling a random gobbledygook of bytes and are telling the browser to interpret it as UTF-8. The standard PHP `str` functions assume *one byte = one character*. By randomly picking a multi-byte string apart with those you're not going to get whole *characters*, only bytes.

If you need *encoding aware* functions operating on a *character level* rather than a byte level, use the `mb_*` functions.

And read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `mb_*` functions, you could alternatively set the following variables in `php.ini` if you have access to it:

```
# following mbstring-variables should be set via php.ini or vhost-configuration (httpd.conf);
# does not work per directory/via .htaccess
mbstring.language = Neutral
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.func_overload = 7
```

That way you could use your current function as it is and use `strlen` or similar functions as if they were a `mb_strlen` function.

See [php.net – Function Overloading Feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) for more details.

See also:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.language
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.internal-encoding

Comment: I would never recommend overloading the `str` functions. Developers expecting them to work on bytes will suddenly see bugs and have very little other tools to work with byte strings.

Comment: @deceze If this is documented, it is a perfectly valid way to use, multibyte functions.

Comment: Yes and no. Since it completely changes the behaviour of existing functions, it may or may not lead to compatibility problems with code that is not aware of this configuration change. Since you're rarely developing in a vacuum and often use other 3rd party libraries, this is a bad idea. Even if you're not doing that *now*, in the future you may run into these issues when your code encounters some 3rd party code.